# Android: Accessing and querying properly using Raw Contact Id

Tags: android, uri, contactscontract, android-contentresolver, rawcontacts

So my app is attempting to integrate a sync adapter to the android native contact manager. This is all running smoothly except once a contact is synced, I am unable to update it. Details on this particular problem can be found here: [Android: Content resolver query returning 0 rows when it ought not to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288384/android-content-resolver-query-returning-0-rows-when-it-ought-not-too/) But I can sum it up simply by just saying my content resolver query is returning 0 values because I am querying the wrong URI, I believe.

When I write the raw contact id to the phone, I do it with the following code:

```
public ContactSyncOperations(Context context, String username,
        String accountName, BatchOperationForSync batchOperation) {

    this(context, batchOperation);
    mBackReference = mBatchOperation.size();
    mIsNewContact = true;
    mValues.put(RawContacts.SOURCE_ID, username);
    mValues.put(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.tagapp.android");
    mValues.put(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
    mBuilder = newInsertCpo(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, true).withValues(mValues);
    mBatchOperation.add(mBuilder.build());
}
```

This constructor method is called when you are adding a new contact to the sync list:

```
private static void addContact(Context context, String account, Contact contact, BatchOperationForSync batchOperation) {
    ContactSyncOperations contactOp = ContactSyncOperations.createNewContact(context, contact.getUsername(), account, batchOperation);//constructor called @ this line
    contactOp.addName(contact.getFirstName(), contact.getLastName());
    contactOp.addEmail(contact.getEmail());
    contactOp.addPhone(contact.getPhoneNumber(), Phone.TYPE_MOBILE);
    contactOp.addPhone(contact.getHomePhone(), Phone.TYPE_HOME);
    contactOp.addPhone(contact.getWorkPhone(), Phone.TYPE_WORK);
    contactOp.addProfileAction(contact.getUsername());
    Log.e("Adding contact", "Via sync");
}
```

As you can see in the constructor, I am calling a method called newInsertCpo, which can be viewed here:

```
private void addInsertOp() {
    if(!mIsNewContact) {
        mValues.put(Phone.RAW_CONTACT_ID, mRawContactId);
    }
    mBuilder = newInsertCpo(addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(Data.CONTENT_URI), mYield);
    mBuilder.withValues(mValues);
    if(mIsNewContact) {
        mBuilder.withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, mBackReference);
    }
    mYield = false;
    mBatchOperation.add(mBuilder.build());
}
```

Now that you can see the code, let me explain the problem. When I am creating and writing the raw contact id, I am doing so to RawContacts.CONTENT_URI:

```
mBuilder = newInsertCpo(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, true).withValues(mValues);
```

However, when I query the uri, I am querying as so:

```
Cursor cursor = resolver.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, DataQuery.PROJECTION, DataQuery.SELECTION, new String[] {String.valueOf(rawContactId)}, null);
```

From Data.CONTENT_URI. I believe this is where my problem is occurring. I used the sample code from Android's official dev site and tailored it for my own uses, but this part is pretty true to the example. Yet it is not working. My lead is what I said, I'm writing to one Uri and querying another. But I've attempted to change the query to RawContacts.CONTENT_URI (which caused an exception), and also changing the Uri I write to Data.CONTENT_URI, which also causes an exception. What's even more confusing is that I get raw contact ids from Data.CONTENT_URI when I do my lookupRawContactId method:

```
private static long lookupRawContact(ContentResolver resolver, String username) {
    Log.e("Looking up Raw Contact", username);
    long authorId = 0;
    Cursor cursor = resolver.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, UserIdQuery.PROJECTION, UserIdQuery.SELECTION, new String[] {username}, null);

    try {
        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            authorId = cursor.getLong(UserIdQuery.COLUMN_ID);
        }
    } finally {
        if(cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return authorId;
}
```

So yea, if I get a cursor returning rawcontactId, why would I get 0 values querying that same Uri with that same rawcontactId i was returned? It doesn't make any sense! Does anyone have any insight? Thanks all.

Comment: What is BatchOperationForSync ? And check if you are storing the proper back reference or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lookupRawContactId method should look like this instead:

```
private static long lookupRawContact(ContentResolver resolver, String username) {
    Log.e("Looking up Raw Contact", username);
    long authorId = 0;
    Cursor cursor = resolver.query(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, UserIdQuery.PROJECTION, UserIdQuery.SELECTION, new String[] {username}, null);

    try {
        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            authorId = cursor.getLong(UserIdQuery.COLUMN_ID);
        }
    } finally {
        if(cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return authorId;
}
```

Notice the query is searching RawContacts.CONTENT_URI instead.

Comment: JMRboosties, Please tel me what is mean by UserIdQuery.PROJECTION. What should i declare for UserIdQuery

Comment: I need Raw ContactID please tel me how can i get the RawContactID

Comment: static final class UserIdQuery { private UserIdQuery() {}     public final static String[] PROJECTION = new String[]{RawContacts._ID}; public final static int COLUMN_ID = 0; public static final String SELECTION = RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "='" + "com.tagapp.android" + "' AND " + RawContacts.SOURCE_ID + "=?";
} Cursor cursor =getContentResolver().query(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, UserIdQuery.PROJECTION, UserIdQuery.SELECTION, new String[]{first_name}, null);         try{
if(cursor.moveToNext()) 
{ 
authorId = cursor.getLong(UserIdQuery.COLUMN_ID);}}